# Apply and remove color profile with image magick

Tags: imagemagick, color-profile

I have Tiff images with embedded specific ICC profiles.

I want to convert these by means of imagemagick to JPG-Files.

The JPG-Files should use colorspace sRGB (which is the default) and **no** embedded profile. In other words I want to apply the profile to the image and want to save it without profile.

When I use a simple convert command like this

```
convert source.tif target.jpg
```

the ICC-Profile is preserved in the JPG file. You can remove it with a command like this

```
convert source.tif +profile "*" target.jpg
```

But that does not seem to apply the profile.

A `-colorspace RGB` (or `-colorspace sRGB`?) should do the trick. But any combination I have tried so far does not work.

Is there a color management guru out there who can give me hint?
`

Answer (score 8):

Some iterations later I come up with this

```
convert source.tif -profile MY_PROFILE_PATH/sRGB.icc +profile * target.jpg
```

I used the ICC profile from http://www.color.org/profiles/srgb_appearance.xalter

Comment: on Debian and derivatives like Ubuntu you can install the package `icc-profiles-free` and use `/usr/share/color/icc/sRGB.icc`.

Comment: I realize this is an absolutely ancient thread but is the first google result when searching for removing the color profile with imagemagick. To extract the profile, you can use `magick convert my_image.png profile.icc` which gives you the embedded profile as `profile.icc`. The command in this answer worked for me: `magick convert ventura.png -profile profile.icc +profile * test.png`. Used this to fix color issues in wallpaper between macOS and Windows 11 (Windows doesn't handle color profiles correctly in wallpapers).